# how to link/add modal value with in existing json object in angular js

Tags: angularjs, json, modal-dialog

below is the html:

```
<tr ng-repeat-start="select in selection">
    <td style="overflow: hidden;">{{select.name}}</td>
    <td style="overflow: hidden;">{{select.type}}</td>
    <td style="overflow: hidden;">{{select.application}}</td>
    <td>
        <image ng-src="{{commentImg}}" width="20" height="20" ng-click="selectComment()"></image>
    </td>
</tr>
```

selectComment opens modal which has textarea. Selection array has 3 key/value per object(i.e. name,type, application). i want to add textarea value as fourth key/value in every object to selection json object.

below is the modal:-

```
   <div class="dialog-panel3">
    <div class="page-title">
        Comments
    </div>
    <br>
    <form name="commentForm">
        <textarea class="textarea" ng-model="inputValue" required></textarea>
        <br>
        <br>
        <button ng-click="comment(inputValue)" ng-disabled="commentForm.$invalid">Save</button>&nbsp;&nbsp
        <button ng-click="close()">Cancel</button>
    </form>

</div>
```

Please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On click of the image which opens the modal, you can save the corresponding index of your JSON object. Create ng-model for your textarea using this index 
to help you link the value with your existing JSON array object.

**HTML**:

```
<tr ng-repeat-start="select in selection">
    <td style="overflow: hidden;">{{select.name}}</td>
    <td style="overflow: hidden;">{{select.type}}</td>
    <td style="overflow: hidden;">{{select.application}}</td>
    <td>
        <image ng-src="{{commentImg}}" width="20" height="20" ng-click="selectComment($index)"></image>
    </td>
</tr>
```

**Contoller**

```
$scope.selectComment=function(index){
  $scope.selection[index].textAreaVal="";
  $scope.selectedIndex=index;
}
```

**Modal**:

```
<div class="dialog-panel3">
    <div class="page-title">
        Comments
    </div>
    <br>
    <form name="commentForm">
        <textarea class="textarea" ng-model="selection[selectedIndex].textAreaVal" required></textarea>
        <br>
        <br>
        <button ng-click="comment(selection[selectedIndex].textAreaVal)" ng-disabled="commentForm.$invalid">Save</button>&nbsp;&nbsp
        <button ng-click="close()">Cancel</button>
    </form>

</div>
```

Comment: how to save the corresponding index of JSON object On click of the image and when i cick on the save button it should add textarea value in json object as new key/value., could you please elaborate

Comment: When you click the image , this function will be called selectComment(), pass the corresponding $index from ng-repeat and save it in a variable(selectedIndex in my answer) and use this to map ur texarea ng-model to the JSON object

Comment: No, it is not working, may be i am using the wrong index variable here :-
 <image ng-click="selectComment($index)"></image>

could you please suggest what should be the index variable here?

Comment: Are you saving the index inside  selectComment($index) function in a new variable like I did. $index is the iterator for ng-repeat. For more info https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat

Comment: can you tell me how to push textarea value in json, selection is the object name.

Comment: You don't have to push the textarea value if you are using the above method.It will be present in textAreaVal key of each object

Comment: Button click code throwing below error:-
ReferenceError: $modalInstance is not defined
    at ChildScope.$scope.comment (ColumnAccessReviewCtrl.js?15b3ebf-20161216-104933:104)
    at fn (eval at compile (angular.js?15b3ebf-20161216-104933:14817), <anonymous>:4:638)
    at expensiveCheckFn (angular.js?15b3ebf-20161216-104933:15906)

Comment: Did you pass $modalInstance in your controller and accept answer if it helped you @ABA :)

Comment: yes vivz, i am trying this code and if it will work, i ll definitely accept answer.
can you please tell me how to pass modalinstance, thanks in advance for cooperation

Comment: Can you edit your question with your controller code?

Comment: $scope.comment = function (index) {
                                         
                                            
                                            
                                            $scope.selectedIndex=index;
                                            
                                            $modalInstance.close('');
                                            
                                        };

Comment: Show your controller declaration, not your function declaration

Comment: controller('ColumnAccessReviewCtrl',
                function ($scope, $filter, $location, $modal, ColumnARService, PLUGIN_URL_BASE)

Comment: Put $modalInstance here also

Comment: This is from which plugin? Check their documentation. Check if all the references are there and also if the functionalities that you are trying to access from this plugin is correct or not. I am sorry, can't help you here because I have not used this plugin

Comment: it is working now, textarea value should be removed from textarea once i click on save, but when i am opening tht modal again it is showing the previous value which i entered, how to remove that?

Comment: your code is working for me, the only problem i am facing is below:-

textarea value should be removed from textarea once i click on save, but when i am opening tht modal again it is showing the previous value which i entered, how to remove that?

Comment: Did you try the above code? $scope.selectComment=function(index){
  $scope.selection[index].textAreaVal="";
  $scope.selectedIndex=index;
}  ????

Comment: Thanks @Vivz, you rock!!